# SQL Server - delete the unnecessary zeros from table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to delete the unnecessary zeros when displaying this table

```
Produit | Prix
---------------
   A    | 1000.65400
   B    | 1200.654000
   C    | 2540.6540000
   D    | 1000.25000
   E    | 224000.6540000000
```

I want to get this result :

```
Produit | Prix
---------------
   A    | 1000.654
   B    | 1200.654
   C    | 2540.654
   D    | 1000.25
   E    | 224000.654
```

Any help will be appreciate.
Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to go to 3 decimal places?

Comment: Is `Prix` a `VARCHAR` field? If so, why?

Comment: Please don't ask SQL Server to do this - perform your prettifying where it belongs, in the presentation tier.

Comment: Yes Prix is a varchar(30)

Comment: from this varchar field I want to delete all unnecessary zeros after the point (.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trims leading and trailing unneeded 0's:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET Prix = CASE
  WHEN Prix LIKE '%.%[1-9]%' THEN -- has a non-0 after the decimal point
    REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(Prix, '0', ' '))), ' ', '0')
  WHEN Prix LIKE '%.%' THEN -- only 0's after the decimal point, remove point
    REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(Prix, '0', ' '))), ' ', '0'), '.', '')
  ELSE -- has no decimal point, only trim leading 0's
    REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(Prix, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
  END
```

If you only want to trim trailing:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET Prix = CASE
  WHEN Prix LIKE '%.%[1-9]%' THEN -- has a non-0 after the decimal point
    REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(Prix, '0', ' '))), ' ', '0')
  ELSE -- only 0's after the decimal point, remove point
    REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(Prix, '0', ' '))), ' ', '0'), '.', '')
  END
WHERE Prix LIKE '%.%' -- make sure it's decimal
```

The above replace all `0`s with spaces, uses the built-in trim functions to trim the spaces, then replaces the spaces with `0`s again.

Comment: UPDATE yourTable
SET Prix = CASE WHEN Prix LIKE '%.%'
  THEN
    REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(Prix, '0', ' '))), ' ', '0')
  ELSE -- has no decimal point, only trim leading 0's
    REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(Prix, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
  END this solution works correctly except that it generates an error if we have 23651.0000 --it give --> 23651.   instead of 23651